Cloud Function whit Authentication IAM ERROR 401 (Flutter/Firebase)
I can't secure our cloud functions. The calls fail when I try to call them with HttpsCallable or HttpsCallableFromUrl. It always gives me a 401 ERROR even though the service accounts appear to be configured correctly.
Code Flutter
final result = await firebaseFunctions
          .httpsCallableFromUrl(
            'https://us-central1-NAME_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/Prova'
          )
          .call();

Code Cloud Function
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions/v2");
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
const { onCall } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");



initializeApp();

exports.Prova = onCall(async (data) => {

  try {
    
    return { success: true, message: 'ok' };
       
    
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error.message);
    return{ message: 'Error' };
    //res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal Error' });
  }
});

Log Cloud Function
2024-11-25 18:33:09.832 CET
POST401 0 B 0 ms com.TEAM.NAMEAPP.dev/0.0.18 iPhone/17.4 hw/sim  https://us-central1-NAME_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/Prova 
{
httpRequest: {14}
insertId: "6744b4d5000ce64c3251f6a2"
jsonPayload: null
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/NAME_PROJECT/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
operation: null
payload: "textPayload"
protoPayload: null
receiveLocation: "us-central1"
receiveTimestamp: "2024-11-25T17:33:09.853205510Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "WARNING"
sourceLocation: null
spanId: "5d2908f5a604aad7"
split: null
textPayload: "The request was not authorized to invoke this service. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#401"
timestamp: "2024-11-25T17:33:09.832156Z"
trace: "projects/NAME_PROJECT/traces/d0f2a1b62b9b9d729cb95b03ad853ca5"
traceSampled: true
}

Log StackTrace
I would like my functions to be private with authentication...

Callable type functions don't ever use IAM to authenticate.  They use Firebase Authentication end user accounts, as they are meant to be called directly from your web or mobile app, typically by Firebase end users.
Firebase Authentication isn't interchangeable with GCP IAM.  They are completely different ways of performing authentication.  Also, you can't provide IAM credentials with a callable request when using the Firebase SDK to make the request.
If you must use IAM, then don't bother with a callable function at all - just build a normal HTTP type function.  Also beware that including IAM credentials in your web or mobile app would typically be considered a security problem, as you aren't supposed to distribute your service accounts to the public.  IAM credentials are only typically used for authenticating backend-to-backend communication.

Ok, thanks Doug, so basically to authenticate with firebase users I will have to put the public function and insert the control with "data.auth". Right? and in case I have to call another function inside a function both with this control, how should I proceed?

Functions that are meant to be called from web and mobile apps need to have public IAM permissions.  There is no alternative to that.  If you have another question, please post it separately (not here in comments) and explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish, and what isn't working the way you expect.

You're right, I opened the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79231907/28483796 .Thank you

Call functions from your app points to
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node/quickstarts/callable-functions gives you a working basic example to start from.

The HTTPS Callable functions Quickstart demonstrates how to send
requests to a server-side function and get a response back using one
of the Client SDKs. It interoperates with the Web, iOS and Android
quickstarts.

