Calling a cloud function "OnCall" from another function "OnCall" (with token)
I need to secure my Cloud Functions and I don't know how to call a function from another function by passing it the right Firebase token. How do I generate a valid idToken?
1°Function


const { logger, HttpsError } = require("firebase-functions/v2");
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { onCall } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

initializeApp();

exports.Prova = onCall(async (data) => {
  try {
    // Verifica se l'utente è autenticato
    if (!data.auth) {
      throw new HttpsError("unauthenticated", "L'utente non è autenticato");
    }
    const idToken = ??
    const callResponse = await fetch('https://us-central1-NAME_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/Prova2', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}` 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "data": {}
        })
    });

    return { success: true, message: "Success" };
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error("Errore:", error.message);
    return { success: false, message: "Errore interno", details: error.message };
  }
});



2° Function


const { logger } = require("firebase-functions/v2");
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { onCall } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");


initializeApp();

exports.Prova2 = onCall(async (data) => {

   // Verifica se l'utente è autenticato
  if (!data.auth) {
    throw new HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'L\'utente non è autenticato');
  }
 
    try {
    return{ message: 'Success' };
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error.message);
    return{ message: 'Error' };
  }
});



Let me start by saying that I make client-side calls with FirebaseFunction.instance.httpCallable(). Someone help me?

Instead of having the first cloud function call a second cloud function, it would be faster, cheaper, and easier if you just call a normal JavaScript function instead.  You can reuse that function in both places if needed.  Callable functions "consume" the ID token provided by the client without passing it along to your code, so it's not exactly straightforward to reconstitute that.

Also, Firebase doesn't provide a client library for invoking callable functions from a backend (only frontend).  You'd have to implement the callable protocol on your own, or find some other library to do that for you - also not nearly as straightforward or easy as simply calling a shared JS function.

The onCall() Firebase Cloud Function is triggered when it's explicitly called from a client application using the Firebase SDKs for mobile, or web. So such an invocation is typically initiated through a function call in your application's code. That being said, I cannot see any reason why you would need to call onCall from inside another onCall function. As @DougStevenson already mentioned in his comment, it would be cheaper and faster to use a regular JavaScript function instead. Keep also in mind that all Firebase Callable Functions utilize and validate the ID token provided by the client.
As Doug Stevenson's recommendation in the comment will definitely work, I recommend you simply change your logic and change the second function into a regular JavaScript function to not overcomplicate your code.

Hey Luciano. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
